# Check NAN values java

Tags: java, nan

It maybe silly question but I need to check if the value of a cell is NAN which means (1/zero) and then convert it to zero I tried the following code

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
do some calculation to get cell[i]
if(cell[i]==NAN)cells[i]=0;}
```

But this doesn't work because java can't recoginize the variable NAN what I should put instead of NAN
Thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean `null`? what is (1/zero) ?

Comment: `0.0/0.0` will get you an `NaN`, not `1.0/0.0`, which will get you `Infinity`.

Comment: Thanks it works fine I used Double.isNaN() method but I have another problem I am getting both positive and negavtive infinity I need to set the positive infinity to one and the negative infinity to zero what you suggest guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the type of your array, use `Double.isNaN()` or `Float.isNaN()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`Double.isNan(double)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN-double-).  Comparisons with `==` with `NaN`s are always `false`.

```
if (Double.isNan(cell[i]))
```